# Woocommerce product form fields

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, product

I would like my product page that customers fill 5 text fields and choose 1 field type radio.

So my product page is a form where customers ask a question, fill some information and choose a paid option.

Like this french page => http://www.avocat-bervard.com/paiement-honoraires-consultation-juridique/

Is it possible with Woocommerce ?

If so, can you explain me how ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create nice forms with plugin Ninja Forms :). Its a very cool plugin, with a couple of settings: sending emails, when submitting forms, etc.

It is also supports shortcodes, with this method you can implement your form on every single product page, or even display it in a widget area.

**For widget area:**
You need to enable shortcodes first in functions.php

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Then call the shortcode in Appearence - Widgets

**For template:**
You need to edit the file where you want this form to display, single-product.php, meta.php :) etc.
To insert shortcode in template file you need to use the below code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>
```